# Necessary condition of a vector space having only one basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I want to know when a vector space has only one basis.

Comment: You ask a lot of questions which are fairly simple to answer if one thinks about the definitions for more than 10 minutes. Most of those questions are unmotivated and don't include your own attempts to solve the problem. That's not how you learn mathematics.

Comment: ok, i will type my attempts along with the question from now on.

Comment: Good. Often when writing a question, I come up with the answer. Because when we write something in a clean and orderly fashion, the things we missed can sometimes pop out and be more visible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One immediate example is the trivial vector space $V = \{0\}$ over any field.

It has the unique basis $\varnothing$.

For a nontrivial vector space, we note that no basis element can have a nonzero multiple different from itself, and that means the scalar field must be $\mathbb{F}_2$. Further, a basis cannot contain more than one element, since if $v_1 \neq v_2 \in B$, we could replace $v_2$ with $v_1+v_2$ to obtain a different basis. Thus the space must be one-dimensional. It is clear that every one-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_2$ vector space has a unique basis consisting of the nonzero element.

Comment: Oh, alright. You can have two badges. :-)