# Is it possible to have multiple different bases of the same space?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am studying about spaces, basis, and span. I know that a basis $S$ is a set of vectors that span a space $V$. Therefore, we could represent any vector in $V$ as a linear combination of $S$.

So, I am wondering if for a space $V$, is it possible to have two distinct bases $S_1$ and $S_2$ such that $S_1 \neq S_2$? If all vectors can represented as the basis, they should be the same, right? Is a base unique for a space?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468339/necessary-condition-of-a-vector-space-having-only-one-basis

Comment: Bases are highly non-unique. Any two bases have the same cardinality. That's about all one can say.

Comment: Generally, a vector space has many different bases. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, consider $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}; \{(1,0),(1,1)\}; \{(2,3),(17,2)\};\, \dotsc$

Comment: Ok guys, I got it, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your definition of basis is not totally correct. A basis for $V$ is a **linearly independent** set $S\subset V$ such that $S$ spans $V$.

It is not hard to check that any vector space (over an infinite field) has infinitely many bases. In a trivial way, you could vary the length of the vectors to get a different basis, and of course you can do this in infinitely many ways.

But let me show with a simple example how to get infinitely (actually, uncountably many) different bases in $\mathbb R^2$, and all basis with vectors of length one. Fix first the canonical basis in $\mathbb R^2$, i.e. $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$. And now take the two vectors and, preserving the square angle between them, rotate them. You will get again a basis (actually the new basis is also orthonormal), and a different one for every rotation angle $\theta$.

Explicitly, the basis after a rotation $\theta$ is
$$
\{(\cos\theta,\sin\theta),(\sin\theta,-\cos\theta)\}.
$$

Comment: (nitpicking) You can have a finite vector space.

Comment: Good point. I added "over an infinite field" to satisfy the nitpickers :)

Comment: Further nitpick: $\{0\}$ has only one basis.